# Prove $[a]_n$ has a unique representative $r$ where $0\leq r<n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove each congruence class $[a]_n$ in $\mathbb{Z_n}$ has a unique representative $r$ such that $0\leq r<n$.

My proof. Assume to the contrary that $[a]_n$ does not have a unique $r$. That is let $r'$ be the other representative such that $r\neq r'$ and $0\leq r,r'< n$.  By the division algorithm and our assumption it follows that $a=nq+r$ and $a=nq'+r'$ where $q, q'\in\mathbb{Z}$.But it follows that $nq+r=nq'+r'\implies nq-nq'=r'-r\implies n|(r'-r)\implies r'\equiv r \pmod{n} $. But since we assumed $0\leq r,r'< n$ it follows that $r=r'$ a contradiction. Would this be correct?

Comment: At the end, aren't you assuming what you are trying to prove? Better maybe to go from $n\mid(r'-r)$ to $r'-r=nq$ to ($r'-r=0$ or $|r'-r|\ge n$), etc.

Comment: "Has a unique representative" requires you to prove that it has a representative in the interval, and that there cannot be more than one. The first part has not been done.

Comment: I used proof by contradiction so I get to assume $[a]_n$ has two different representatives I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just divide any integer number by n and the existence of such a representative is straightforward from Euclid's division theorem. Your prove about uniqueness is good and acceptable intuitively, but it's not completely rigorous I think. You can go one step further in your argument and say $n|(r-r')$ gives $n \leq |r-r'|$. but $0 \leq r<n$ and $0 \leq r'<n$ gives $0 \leq|r-r'|<n$ .But if $|r-r'| \neq 0$ we'll have $|r-r'| < |r-r'|$ which is absurd. Therefore $|r-r'| =0$ and because both $r$ and $r'$ are positive we must have $r= r'$